# Can i share image to a facebook page using facebook SDK in android studio?

Tags: android, facebook-page, facebook-sdk-4.0

I was able to share image or text to the facebook wall using facebook sdk. But can i share image with text to a specific facebook page using facebook sdk using android studio?